# NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I wrote this to upload an image to s3 and I only get this error on my test server, on `localhost` profile picture upload successfully without getting an error. `php.ini` files are same on both `localhost` and `testing` environments. Also AWS Credentials given right.

On test server code execute into `if (!File::exists($folderPath)) {` To my knowledge I wrote that part. Here's the code.

```
                if ((strpos($profilePic, 'data:image/png;base64,') !== false)
                    || (strpos($profilePic, 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') !== false)) {

                    $img = Image::make($profilePic)->orientate();
                } else {
                    
                    $img = Image::make(base64_decode($profilePic))->orientate();
                }

                $original = 'avater.png';
                $small = 'avater_small.png';
                $medium = 'avater_medium.png';

                $folderPath = 'uploads/profile_pictures/'.$userId;

                $fullPath = $folderPath.'/'.$original;
                $fullPathSmall = $folderPath.'/'.$small;
                $fullPathMedium = $folderPath.'/'.$medium;
                
                if (!File::exists($folderPath)) {
                    File::makeDirectory($folderPath, 0775, true);
                }

                $smallImg = clone $img;
                $mediumImg = clone $img;

                if ($img->height() > $img->width()) {
                    // resize the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio          
                    $smallImg->resize(400, null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });

                    $mediumImg->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                } else {
                    // resize the image to a height of 200 and constrain aspect ratio
                    $smallImg->resize(null, 400, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });

                    $mediumImg->resize(null, 400, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                }

                $img->save($fullPath);
                $smallImg->save($fullPathSmall);
                $mediumImg->save($fullPathMedium);
                Storage::disk('s3')->put($fullPath, file_get_contents($profilePic), 'public');
                Storage::disk('s3')->put($fullPathMedium, file_get_contents($profilePic), 'public');
                Storage::disk('s3')->put($fullPathSmall, file_get_contents($profilePic), 'public');

                $user_repository = \App::make('App\Repositories\Contracts\UserRepositoryInterface');

                // $data = ['profile_image' => asset('uploads/profile_pictures/'.$userId.'/'.$original)];
                $data = ['profile_image' => '/uploads/profile_pictures/'.$userId.'/'.$original];

                $item_image = $user_repository->updateUser($userId,$data);

                return true;
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about error ? Like which line of your code is giving this error

Comment: @ForamkumarPatel please see this. https://sentry.io/share/issue/e6f2abdb03c4433f9c9c0c77d8285c6f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is permission issue for your upload folder on your testing server. Please verify that because before upload to s3 bucket you are storing your image to your upload folder first.

Comment: how did I miss that. such primary case. Thank you for opened my eyes!